# Constructive induction to find a formula for a summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I am looking to find the values of a b and c for an equation of this summation, but am getting lost on how to solve it.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 12^i = an2^n + b2^n + c$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} 12^i = \sum_{i=1}^n 12^i + 12^{n+1}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 12^i + 12^{n+1} = a(n+1)2^{n+1} + b2^{n+1} + c$$
Replace the sum with its equation
$$an2^n + b2^n + c + 12^{n+1} = a(n+1)2^{n+1} + b2^{n+1} + c$$
Cancel out the c, multiply the a
$$an2^n + b2^n + 12^{n+1} = (an+a)2^{n+1} + b2^{n+1}$$
I know when solving this problem with polynomials you can compare coefficients of like powers to find a and b, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: There are no $a,b,c$ such that the equation holds for all $n$.

Comment: This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  Whenever $r\neq 1$ you have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n r^i = \frac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.  In particular, this implies that the sum should be on the order $12^n$ which is much larger than on the order of $n2^n$.  I feel that this implies that no such $a,b,c$ exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the geometric series
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n 12^i = \frac{12^{n+1}-12}{12-1}
$$
We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n 12^i = \frac{12^{n+1}-12}{11} - 1 = \frac{12}{11}\, 12^n-\frac{23}{11} = O(12^n) = O(6^n \cdot 2^n)
\overset{!}{=}
a \, n \, 2^n + b \, 2^n + c
$$
this should grow much faster than any linear combination of $n 2^n$ and $2^n$.

So you can not replace that sum for all values of $n$ with your expression.